# how can i set s3 user-agent key of header with any other value(say "mystring") using boto

Tags: amazon-s3, user-agent, boto, authorize

I have passed the header with User-Agent set to the make_request() function of AWSConnection class in connection.py and found that this is getting overriden by the hard-coded value in the authorize() of HttpRequest class , this authorization is done from _mexe() . Now i want to skip this overriding without changing boto code or Is there any other way with which i can achieve my goal.
Boto version used : 2.32.1

Answer (score 0):

Boto uses the value of `boto.UserAgent` as the `User-Agent` header.  You should be able to override this.

```
import boto
boto.UserAgent = 'MyCoolAgent 1.0'
```

Does that work for you?